# Find the limit of the sequence $\{\frac{x_1 + 2x_2 + ... + nx_n}{n^2}\}$, where $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence in a normed space S.

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

> Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a convergent sequence in a [normed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) $(S, ||\cdot ||)$. Find the limit of the sequence
> \begin{align}
> \left\{\frac{x_1 + 2x_2 + \cdots + nx_n}{n^2}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty} .
> \end{align}

Could you please give me some hints where to start?

Comment: Start from a constant sequence. This will give you a hint on what's the limit in the general case. If the sequence is not constant, nevertheless it's true that eventually all terms will be near their limit. How can you estimate how far is your sum from the guessed limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Stolz–Cesàro theorem, which is a l'Hôpital's rule for sequences.

Let $a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n ix_i$, and $b_n=n^2$. We have 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} = \frac{(n+1)x_{n+1}}{2(n+1)-1} \rightarrow \frac{x}{2}, when \ \   n\rightarrow \infty$$
so $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $\frac{x}{2}$.

Of course $\delta-\epsilon$ arguments should work here too.

Answer (score 2):

For $\varepsilon > 0$ choose $N>0$ such that $n>N \Longrightarrow |x_n-x|<\varepsilon$. Now, since $\frac{1+2+\dots+n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{x_1+2x_2+\dots+nx_n}{n^2} - \frac{x}{2} \right|&= \left| \frac{x_1+2x_2+\dots+nx_n}{n^2} - \left(\frac{1+2+\dots+n}{n^2} -  \frac{1}{2n} \right)x \right|\\
& = \left| \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(x_k-x) + \frac{x}{2n} \right| \\
& = \left| \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}k(x_k-x) + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}k(x_k-x) + \frac{x}{2n} \right| \\
& \leqslant \left| \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}k(x_k-x) \right| + \left| \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}k(x_k-x) \right| + \left| \frac{x}{2n} \right| \\
& \leqslant  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left|k(x_k-x)\right|  +  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}\left|k(x_k-x) \right| + \left| \frac{x}{2n} \right|
 \\
& \leqslant  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left|k(x_k-x)\right|  +  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}k \varepsilon + \left| \frac{x}{2n} \right| \\
& \leqslant 3 \varepsilon
\end{align}

for $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 1):

*This looks a bit like Cesáro mean taken a level higher.*

Let $x=\lim x_n$. First, guess the correct limit in terms of $x$  - for example by considering the case of a constant given sequence $\{x_n\}$.
Then, make and $\epsilon$-proof: For given $\epsilon>0$, we have $kx_k\approx kx$ for $k$ big enough. On the other hand the contribution of the first summands gets negligible as $n\to \infty$ as it is divided by $n^2$.

I suppose you can fill in the details from these hints.