# Limit of the weighted sum of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that it converges to $x$. Then $\frac{x_1+2x_2+...+nx_n}{n^2}\rightarrow \frac{x}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Any help is appreciated. It would be great if an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument is provided.

EDIT: I had written the limit incorrectly. I guessed that it should have been the limit, but now I think it is $\frac{x}{2}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931703/find-the-limit-of-the-sequence-fracx-1-2x-2-nx-nn2-where